# Header and Nav are fixed, but my div is not appearing under both elements

Tags: html, css

so when I go to set both Nav and Header to fixed, it starts out fine. I adjust the Nav margin-top so that it appears under the header, that works. Now when I adjust the div, that's where things go wrong. So the div of course appears behind the fixed elements, and when I go to adjust the div's top margin it brings everything with it. How do I get it so that the divs stays below my header and nav bar so this:

So I want the header, nav, and footer to be stationary, and the div to be the only scrolling section of my website. I set both my header and nav to "position:fixed", though when I test it, my non-"fixed" div appears over the fixed elements. Whenever I try to move the div down by adjusting its "margin-top" it moves everything along with it. With the div, header, footer, and nav all overlapping each other. So how do I get that to not do it?

Comment: Please provide code, http://jsfiddle.net or anything that shows what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "fixed" elements are being pushed down by your div, because you are not setting a `top` property.
When you don't set the `top` property, even the fixed elements will be rendered on the relative place where they would appear naturally.

Replace the `margin-top` property for `top`, and it will fix your issue. Also, give `top:0px` to your fixed element that doesn't have a `margin-top`.

Here are two examples showing this behaviour:

With `margin-top`: http://jsfiddle.net/HnZpN/ (issue)
With `top`: http://jsfiddle.net/HnZpN/1/

Comment: Your awesome, thanks for the quick response, I'll try that. This was getting annoying for me.

Comment: Thanks I just tried it, worked amazingly well. New problem though: I have a background image, and I changed the z-index to 1 on the header and nav, but since both are transparent n background the divs are visible behind them when scrolling, is there a way to allow the background to not be affected and yet still hide the div when its behind the header.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rccrf/Zs324/5/

here's the code site, I added the background color so you could see the elements.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand what you said. What do you want to happen?

Comment: Okay old problem fixed, new problem: Div is visible behind header when scrolling since there isn't a background for the header elements (header and nav). I want to hide the Div when it gets into the header zone without affecting the background image. Since I had the thought of using a background color behind the header, but then that would obscure the background.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think it can be done. You're talking about hiding an element, but keeping visible the one behind it, and the one in front of it. Maybe you should reconsider your page structure and rethink the visual you are trying to achieve. And, as long as possible, try to keep the layout elements on the same level.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that, but I shan't give up hope. I think my answer lies in javascript. You've been amazingly helpful, I was getting to a breaking point. damn shame this site has dumb rules since I'd like to upvote you, but you need 15 reputation points (also 10 to post a picture, that's annoying). I'll share my findings with everyone if I find a solution.